# Why i am getting the Warn Messages also in my logger when configured to get from INFO Level

Tags: log4j

I have this log4j.xml file which should only log from INFO Level
but i was also getting the WARN Level also in my log .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
   <appender class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender" name="FILE">
      <param value="D:\\RAM\\tst.log" name="File" />
      <param value="10" name="MaxBackupIndex" />
      <param value="200MB" name="MaxFileSize" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param value="%d[%t] %-5p(%F:&lt;%M&gt;:%L)- %m%n" name="ConversionPattern" />
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <appender class="com.Log4JCustomAppender" name="CUSTAPPEN">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param value="%d[%t] %-5p(%F:&lt;%M&gt;:%L)- %m%n" name="ConversionPattern" />
      </layout>
      </appender>

   <appender class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender" name="ASYNC">
     <param name="Blocking" value="false"/>
     <param name="BufferSize" value="1000"/>
      <appender-ref ref="CUSTAPPEN" />
   </appender>

   <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
      <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
   </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

This is the output i was getting in my Custom Appender and RollingFileAppender

```
LOgged One is 2013-06-23 01:05:55,954[main] FATAL(Hi.java:<main>:14)- This is a fatal Message

LOgged One is 2013-06-23 01:05:55,965[main] WARN (Hi.java:<main>:15)- This is a warn Message
```

please tell me how to avoid this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is normal. Setting a logger to a specific level value indicates that you want that level AND all level above.

Levels are :

- TRACE
- DEBUG
- INFO
- WARN
- ERROR
- FATAL
- OFF

If you want only the `INFO` level, you have to use filters on your appenders :

```
<filter type="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
  <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
  <levelToMatch  value="INFO" />
</filter>
<filter type="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter" />
```

Comment: my mistake , absolutely sorry for wasting time of others , i thought it  WARN is before  INFO , thanks for the clarification , and that filter match is very useful , thanks once again .

Comment: so should i apply this filter in my CustomAppender or inside the AsyncAppender ? Please clarify

Comment: Only on your AsyncAppender. Setting the filter on CustomAppender should give the same result, but it's useless to let AsyncAppender forwarding to CustomAppender if we can filter earlier.

Comment: thanks for the reply , i tried setting this filter match to INFO , its only giving the INFO messages only  not error , fatal or warn , is this normal ??

Comment: Yes, since it explicitly accept INFO and deny all other levels.

Comment: thanks for your time , i got clarified with all my questions .have good time .